# Add the constraint of normalization coefficient for matlab curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to use a custom model to fit some data. The syntax I used is `fit()`. The mathematical model I used has the form of this:

```
a*exp(-x*b)+c*exp(-y*d)+e*exp(-z*f)
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are the parametres I will estimate and `x,y,z` are independent variables. (The actual mathematical formula is more complicated but something nonlinear like this.)

How can I add the constraint of `a+c+e=1` (and `a,c,e` must be positive or 0) when fitting the curve? I know how to set the lower and upper bound but don't know how to add this normalization coefficient constraint to the fitting. Is it possible to do this when using the `fit()` method?

Comment: Can't you just use `a*exp(-x*b)+c*exp(-y*d)+(1-a-c)*exp(-z*f)`?

Comment: In this case the a+c could be larger than 1?

Comment: Using `1-a-c` instead of `e` is equivalent to the restriction `a+c+e+1`, just that

Comment: I just edited the question to make clear that a c e should also be positive. Actually a c e have physical meaning. So 1-a-c may result in a negative e?

Comment: @BigBO. Please, joint to your question a representative example of data (numerical, not graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I already posted this somewhere, but can't find it right now.

As it is a non-linear fit, there is no big deal in transforming the parameters. say we chose the continuously differentiable and monotonic function:

`a = f(s) = 1/2 ( 1 + s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) )`

so for `s` in `(-inf, inf)` on gets `a`  in `(0,1)`. Actually, with some simple shifting and scaling we could get any `a` in `( u, v )`.

Now we can do the same for `b`, but with the additional restriction `a + b + c = 1` we know that at most `c = 0`  and `b` must definitively be smaller than `1 - f(s) = 1/2 ( 1 - s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) )`. Now, hence, is the time for scaling and we can set:

`b = g(t, s) = 1/2 ( 1 - s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) ) 1/2 ( 1 + t / sqrt( 1 + t^2 ) )`

again with `t` in `(-inf, inf)`. The first part is the scaling due to the already set value for `a`, the second part repeats the procedure from above.

Finally, `c`is simply `1- f(s) - g(t, s)`

Eventually, the fit function with parameters `s` and `t` looks like:

```matlab
+ 0.50 * ( 1 + s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) ) * exp( -x * b )
+ 0.25 * ( 1 - s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) ) * ( 1 + t / sqrt( 1 + t^2 ) ) * exp( -y * d )
+ (
    +1.00 
    -0.50 * ( 1 + s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) 
    -0.25 * ( 1 - s / sqrt( 1 + s^2 ) ) * ( 1 + t / sqrt( 1 + t^2 ) )
) * exp( -z * f )
```

Getting results for `s` and `t` provides `a`, `b` and `c` via error propagation

Comment: Thank you. This is a very clever way that using mapping to solve this problem. It inspired me quite much and solved this particular problem. I dont know how this will influence the processing time for my fitting but it is very good. Do you know any way that  using some simple syntax to solve this problem? I mean maybe in the future i may still meet  some fitting problems with constraint. Is there a easier and general way to do it? The parametric method inspired me quite a lot anyway!

Comment: Hi, I've been thinking a bit about generalizations, but haven't come up with something, yet. Very often your generalization is sabotaged by some little "addon" from your new problem, you haven't thought of earlier, anyway. So most of the time, I choose pencil and paper, and figure it out like this. The "tool set" is quite general, though, and simple.